# Multiple APk version controlling android

Tags: android

suppose we have an application have version 1 and after one month due to some changed ,application version turn to version 2 and than after few month we launch version 3 .
Those who have Version 1 not update there phone and on play store have version 3 ,in which only updated changes of version 2 . so HOW are they get version 2 and get proper application which have all functionality of v1,v2,v3 ???????

Comment: v2 changes will be available in v3 right?

Comment: playstore don't update your existing app, it will download new app and install it on phone, so there is no need to worry about it

Comment: v3 have only updates of v2 .v1 have now update for version but now on play v3 available ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, all your users who decide to update will get the latest version installed from play store as long as the `versionCode` in their local version is lesser than the `versionCode` in play store app. In fact, it is your responsibility that your latest version doesn't break the app for your users of previous version

Comment: sorry ,i am not getting your point . my problem to understand how version 1 will get all updates,although version 3 have only updated file of 'version 2' and version 2 have only updated file of 'version 1'

Comment: In the most simplistic terms, Android will change all the files in version 1 with that of version 3. So, if you added a new file in version 2 and updated it in version 3, it will appear as a new file in version 1.

Answer (score 0):

Let us say you have some code which needs to update some persistent info in both version 2 and version 3. Your version 3 app should not assume that it is going to update version 2 only.
 You will have to check if the previous version was version 1 or version 2 and accordingly update the data. You may do it either by analysing the data itself or by keeping some other persistent variable (to track the version) which you would update after the update.